# How to increase execution time out limit in WordPress dashboard?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, performance

One of my plugins creates a time out every time I visit the `Products` admin page in my `WooCommerce` website dashboard. I can't deactivate this plugin as it's absolutely essential for what we do. Any way to increase time out limit?

Comment: time to replace the plugin (pun intended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase your max execution time by adding the following to your .htaccess

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Otherwise update your php.ini file to reflect the max execution time increase.

Comment: This only works when PHP runs as an Apache module.